# Use different tool to display the diff in the Commit window

Tags: tortoisehg

When right-clicking on a file, I can choose *Visual Diff* and it opens in KDiff3.

I would like to use its output immediately in the Commit window. Is this currently possible? *kdiff3* is set as *Three-way Merge Tool* and as *Visual Diff Tool*, and the *extdiff* extension is enabled.

Comment: AFAIK, there's no configuration option to change the view your talking about in TortoiseHG, the default diff command from Mercurial is used. This can't be changed on Mercurial side either. I'd love to be proven wrong, I've always wanted to change this too ^^ I will try some more at work tomorrow...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/manual/2.1/) that is not possible. You can suggest this feature to developers via [discussion](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/tortoisehg-discuss), [developer](http://groups.google.com/group/thg-dev) or [issue](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/tortoisehg-issues) list.